# Python/Django - Set new password

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I'm new at django and got problem with change password, I got no errors but the new password does not save and dont redirect me either?

Here is my form.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q



class NewPasswordForm(forms.Form):


error_messages = {
    'old_password' : ("Your old password was entered incorrectly, Please enter it again"),
    'password_mismatch' : ("The two password fields didn't match"),
}

old_password = forms.CharField(label='Current Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
new_password1 = forms.CharField(label='New Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
new_password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm New Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

field_order = ['old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2']


def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_old_passpord(self):
# Validate that the old_password field is correct.
    if not self.user.check_password(old_password):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['old_password'],
                code = 'old_password'
        )
    return old_password

def clean_new_password2(self):
    old_password = self.cleaned_data.get('old_password')
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        if password1 == old_password:
            raise ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                    code = 'password_mismatch'
                )
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    password = self.cleaned_data["new_password1"]
    self.user.set_password(password)
    if commit:
        self.user.save()
    return self.user
```

Here is my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import NewPasswordForm
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, update_session_auth_hash
#Don't forget login_required
def user_change_password_view(request):
    form = NewPasswordForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(self.request, form.user)
            return redirect(home_view) # Redirect to a success page
        else:
            form = NewPasswordForm(request.POST or None)
     template = 'change_password.html'
     context = {
        'form' : form
     }
     return render(request, template, context)
```

Lika I said, no errors at all, but nothing happens, it just refreshes page. 
Can put in anything without telling its wrong.

Yes I use a custom user model, if that is to any help...

Sorry for bad english but I hope you get it. All help matters <3

Comment: If it shows you the same page that means either you don't go into `request.method == 'POST'` or it means your form isn't valid (that's what your code does). If the fields of your form are emptied, it means the request method isn't POST, if the fields are still there it means the form isn't valid. You should print your form errors in your template to see them or you should set a breakpoint on the `return render(...)` line and check the `form.errors` in your debugger.

Comment: by the way: your `NewPasswordForm` takes a `user` in its initialiser. But you don't initialise it that way (in your case `user = request.POST`). You should initialise with a `user`: `form = NewPasswordForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST or None)`

Comment: Don't change the signature of the form.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you! That help me alot! Got an error about update_session_auth_hash(self.request, form.user) but just removed "self" and now it works like a charm :D